# Why image in ImageSlider only one is shown?

Tags: android, arrays, json, hashmap

I use the [daimajia imageslider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library to get my url image data from a database, but it is not working correctly. The image in the imageslider only shows one. Can anyone help me for solution to fix this?

Thank you :)

### This is my code to get data

```
StringRequest stringRequestSlider = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppServer.URL_Select_Iklan,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Iklan", response);
                    try {
                        ArrayList<Iklan> iklanList = new JsonConverter<Iklan>().toArrayList(response, Iklan.class);
                        HashMap<String, String> url_maps = new HashMap<>();
                        for (Iklan iklan : iklanList) {
                            url_maps.put(iklan.getJudul_iklan(), AppServer.URL_Select_Poster + iklan.getPoster_iklan());
                        }

                        Log.d("HashMap response", String.valueOf(url_maps));

                        for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
                            sliderView.description(name).image(url_maps.get(name)).setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                            sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
                            sliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                            sliderView.getBundle().putString("extra", name);

                            Log.d("Value of HashMap", name);

                            sliderLayout.addSlider(sliderView);
                        }

                        sliderLayout.setCustomIndicator((PagerIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_indicator));
                        //sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
                        sliderLayout.setDuration(3500);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    try {
                        pDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

### This is my Iklan class

```
public class Iklan {
public String judul_iklan, poster_iklan;

public Iklan() {
}

public String getJudul_iklan() {
    return judul_iklan;
}

public void setJudul_iklan(String judul_iklan) {
    this.judul_iklan = judul_iklan;
}

public String getPoster_iklan() {
    return poster_iklan;
}

public void setPoster_iklan(String poster_iklan) {
    this.poster_iklan = poster_iklan;
}
}
```

Comment: can you show the server response, your "HashMap response" log result ?

Comment: This is my HashMap response @jemsnaban: `02-24 10:12:23.574 28797-28797/com.ajjunaedi.jmnanywhere D/HashMap response: {Coba5=http://video.jogjamedianet.com/app/mobile/poster/coba5.jpg, Coba3=http://video.jogjamedianet.com/app/mobile/poster/coba3.jpg, Coba2=http://video.jogjamedianet.com/app/mobile/poster/coba2.jpg, Coba4=http://video.jogjamedianet.com/app/mobile/poster/coba4.jpg, Coba1=http://video.jogjamedianet.com/app/mobile/poster/coba1.jpg}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should create new `sliderView` in the foreach statement and add them to `sliderLayout` using `addSlider` method.

```
sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation()); 

for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {         
     sliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getApplicationContext()); //create new sliderview

     sliderView.description(name).image(url_maps.get(name)).setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
     sliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
     sliderView.getBundle().putString("extra", name);

     Log.d("Value of HashMap", name);

     sliderLayout.addSlider(sliderView);
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. I got an error on create new sliderview.